# Can you send token authentication with different sessionid cookie

Tags: angular, http, authentication

I have an application in Angular 6 that launches a number of other legacy applications. The legacy applications use a sessionid cookie for authentication. However, the angular application uses Token authentication. When I open up the legacy applications, a login page is prompted and the sessionid cookie is added. however, when I go back to the angular application and send an http request to my api, the sessionid cookie is sent with it, along with my token authentiaction. having the sessionid causes an Unauthorized error response.

This is remedied by deleting the sessionid cookie, but users should not have to do that all the time.

How do I manage both authentication methods without getting them tied together and causing each other to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are sent automatically by browsers for a specific domain depending on the how the `Set-Cookie` header is configured when returned from the server to the browser.

When you first send a request to the "legacy application", it returns a cookie that is stored in your browser for that specific domain, i.e. example.com. Any subsequent http requests that you make to example.com or example.com/api will cause the browser to automatically send that cookie along.

Based on your description, it seemed that both your "legacy login application" and "API" (that requires token authentication) is hosted on the same domain or subdomain.

You can change your DNS settings such that your "legacy login application" is on a different subdomain than your "API". e.g. legacyapp.example.com and api.example.com. And ensure that it returns a cookie without `Set-Cookie: domain=example.com` which would cause browsers to send the cookie to both subdomains since example.com is a higher level domain.